# Crystal drive level and oscillator accuracy

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, oscillator, crystal

I'm using [LAN8830](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN8830-Data-Sheet-00004724A.pdf) as an ethernet phy and from preliminary tests the network works.
However, upon analyzing the operation of the quartz connected to the LAN8830, we found that it is over-driven even if the quartz characteristics meet the specifications in TABLE 6-20 of the LAN8830 datasheet.

We actually measure a drive level of about 600uW, which exceeds the level of our quartz (200uW) even if we choose a quartz with a very low load capacity and a fairly high drive capacity.

Is there any way to decrease the oscillator drive level without compromising the oscillator accuracy?
The quartz is an Epson [TSX-3225 25.0000MF20X-AJ3](https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_TSX-3225&lang=en)

Comment: How did you measure the drive level? Could there be an error measuring it? What does the waveform look like? Have you tried a series resistor?

Comment: Oh, can you tell me where should i place the series resistor? Between XIN and crystal or XOUT and crystal? Any suggestion with the series resistor values?

Comment: Also there is no way to figure out what parameters the exact crystal you ordered has. What's the exact part number to figure out basic things like load capacitance, accuracy and tolerance? Post the schematics and PCB layout too, maybe there is an error. But you still did not say how you measured crystal power, it may be measured wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended drive level for that crystal is 10 μW so, given that your circuit delivers it 600 μW, the only sensible recourse is to choose a suitable crystal for the job. Image from [data sheet](https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?dl=brief_TSX-3225&lang=en): -

[image]

> *Is there any way to decrease the oscillator drive level without
> compromising the oscillator accuracy?*

The accuracy is already compromised by using too much power so, choose the correct crystal for the application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did check your answer. However, in the ESR line in your attached image, in the conditions/remarks column, the DL is mentioned as 100uW. So, the drive level is recommended as 10uW. But the manufacturer himself has already tested at a higher drive level, right?

Comment: The drive level is not recommended at 100 uW and, it's impossible to say what tests the manufacturer has done without asking them. All I can say is that they recommend a drive level of 10 uW and, through testing or calculation or iteration or some other method, they state a maximum level of 200 uW @Freshman

Comment: @Freshman are we done here now? Can you accept my answer or do you need more information?

Comment: Sure, I have accepted the answer